# How to display json into uitextview from NSDictionary

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, xcode

I'm trying now for the whole weekend to get simple data back from mysql database into Json into my app into a nice UItextview.

***this is my php code:***

```
<?PHP

include("Connection.php");

$query="Select * from Api";

 $result=mysql_query($query,$conn);     

    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
    $users[]=$row1;
    }


$body = array();

if (!empty($users))
    $body['users'] = $users;

if (!empty($body))
    echo json_encode ($body);


    include("dbClose.php");     
?>
```

***this is my Xcode code:***

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:JSON];
    NSLog(@"jsonreturn#########=%@",url);
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *jsondata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSDictionary *dic = nil;

    if (!jsondata)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Data not found !!." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }

    //  NSLog(@"data %@",data);

    dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsondata options:0 error:&error];

       [_userEmail removeAllObjects];
       [_userFirst removeAllObjects];


      NSLog(@"Dictionary data %@",dic);



    for (NSDictionary *obj in [dic objectForKey:@"users"]) {

        ;
        [_userEmail addObject:[obj valueForKey:@"Email"]];


    }



   user_mail.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dic valueForKey: @"Email"]];
```

this is the log in Xcode you can see here the ***email*** so as you can see the data parsing is good:

```
Dictionary data {
users =     (
            {
        0 = 1;
        1 = "dani\t";
        10 = "";
        11 = "";
        12 = 0;
        2 = "l\f)\U008f\U00d0\U00b7`\U00fcR\U0092\U00bauU\U00f2]";
        3 = dani;
        4 = dani;
        5 = "";
        6 = "";
        7 = "";
        8 = dani;
        9 = dani;
        Country = "";
        Email = "dani\t";
        "First_Name" = dani;
```

and this is the app ***UItextview*** result for the email:

```
(null)
```

so as you can see my problem here is how to i get the value from the NSDictionary to be displayed in the app as a textview I don't want to use table view or something not such my code above so, please stick to this and any help will be great thank you all.

It is very basic I just got my database and want to select some code and return that code into my app into a UItextview any other way to do so will be great, every way work for me just show me how to do this I got crazy over the weekend searching for a solution for this and nothing just nothing on the web for json and textview!.

Comment: well, according to your log output, the "dic objectForKey:@"users"" is empty

Comment: users are just the body look at the php code, I am using json_encode so the body is just users  $body['users'] = $users; its have nothing to do with it it should be empty the important thing is the email therefore email is equal = dani how do I put "dani" into uitextview? oh and btw users is not empty I have just copied the important part of the log not all of it any way the users is just the body and it shows you all what inside the users lets say you can change users to emails in your'e mind to understand me... so you have emails: and here is the first email from the database "dani".

Comment: If that's the case, you might want to edit your log output so we can see what you're actually getting back as a response.

Comment: there I edited it as you can see it's pretty simmiller just some extra information you don't even need.. any help with my qustion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your output from the log is this:

```
Dictionary data {
users =     (
        {
    0 = 1;
    1 = "dani\t";
    10 = "";
    11 = "";
    12 = 0;
    2 = "l\f)\U008f\U00d0\U00b7`\U00fcR\U0092\U00bauU\U00f2]";
    3 = dani;
    4 = dani;
    5 = "";
    6 = "";
    7 = "";
    8 = dani;
    9 = dani;
    Country = "";
    Email = "dani\t";
    "First_Name" = dani;
    }
)}
```

Then the dictionary of data contains a dictionary with key "users".

Inside the "users" dictionary you have an array. In the log "(" equals array, "{" equals dictionary, for json strings.

Inside the array of users, object 0 has a dictionary with several keys (0,1,10,11..Country,Email...)

So to put the value of the key "Email" in a label, you could do this:

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsondata options:0 error:&error];

NSArray *users = [dic objectForKey:@"users"];
NSDictionary  *firstUser = [users objectAtIndex:0];
user_mail.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [firstUser valueForKey: @"Email"]];
```

You could iterate the array to go do this for all objects in the "users" array, or if you know you want the first or last, you could do NSDictionary  *firstUser = [users firstObject] or     NSDictionary  *firstUser = [users lastObject].

I hope that helps.

Comment: You're amazing so quick answer great ! you're my god thank you mate much much helped thank you so much it worked like magic. so what I was missing is just an array that would hold my users? and what is the diffrent between nsarray and nsmutablearray?

Comment: wow...thanks. Oh and don't forget to mark it as answered so it can help other people ;)