# How to use "INNER JOIN" query to match the user's Profile to his Email In iPhone

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, iphone, xcode

My PHP Code:

```
<?PHP

$email=$_GET['Email']; 

include("Connection.php");

$query="Select * from Api INNER JOIN Api_User
ON         Api_User.Email = Api.Email where Api_User.Email='$email'";

 $result=mysql_query($query,$conn);     

    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
    $users[]=$row1;
    }

$body = array();

if (!empty($users))
    $body['users'] = $users;

if (!empty($body))
    echo json_encode ($body);

    include("dbClose.php");     
?>
```

My Xcode Code:

```
    #pragma Get User Information (This is the Profile for the user!):

    -(void)getUserURL{

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:JSON];
        NSLog(@"jsonreturn#########=%@",url);
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *jsondata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsondata options:0 error:&error];
        //NSArray *users = [dic objectForKey:@"users"];
        //NSDictionary  *firstUser = [users objectAtIndex:0];
        for (NSDictionary *obj in [dic objectForKey:@"users"]) {

            user_Mail.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [obj valueForKey: @"Email"]];
            NSLog(@"Dictionary data is %@",obj);
        }

}
```

My Xcode Log from the data:

```
2015-01-01 18:02:26.870  Dictionary data is (null)
```

My MySql Order is two Tables:
Api = first table
Api_User = second table

***Image (Api) structure*** : [link 1](http://oi62.tinypic.com/mjrgo0.jpg)

***Image (Api_User) structure*** :[link 2](http://oi59.tinypic.com/2mex2qv.jpg)

Ok so as you can see I got a few problems here first of all my php code i'm trying to match each user to his account so he can see his email he had login with in is profile ViewController in the app...
Then in Xcode i'm trying to get the json_encode from the php code and turn into NSDictionray without making an array to store, when I did it with the array it worked but I could only use "objectAtIndex" as you can see in the comment (//objectAtIndex) but it only get me the users i put the number of him from the mysql for example user 1,2,3 and It dont use $GET to match users with the email so now my qustion is how can I match each user to is specific info he have in my database to the iphone so he can see is details in a profile viewcontroller with NSDictionray and INNER JOIN query?

- I have in mysql two tables one names Api and one name Api_User the idea is to match between the email and userID to the current user that is logged in, (with $GET Email) and then to show him is profile and display is email into a uitext with NSDictionray.

*In other words I got my registration where its just $POST Email for instance ok, then Login and now I need Profile code so users can see their info in the IOS app.

*What am Im doing wrong in every part?, should I use Core Data instead?, what should I do how does big apss does this task I see this on over more than a million apps so how do they do it?

*Also please have look on this question to better understanding me: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693061/how-to-display-json-into-uitextview-from-nsdictionary)
In there (in the question) he get the user profile only by Objectatindex so it's not really good since you can't get the user you want by his email or the user you need you just getting the row for the database by it number...

Comment: PHP's mysql_ API is long since deprecated. See mysqli_ (or PDO) and prepared statements

Comment: Mate I just called my database API its not part of mysql_API its just a simple database I created my self...

Comment: I know. But you're still using deprecated (and insecure) code.